# Body min-width issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width

I am currently experimenting locally with Vantage theme(Wordpress)
[Link](http://siteorigin.com/theme/vantage/)

I want to set minimum width of the page in order to stop scaling down content when browser window is being narrowed.

It works perfectly on their site (at around 1020px width website stops scaling), and I wonder what is the trick to make it happen.

I have tried going with

```
min-width:1080px;
```

And it works nicely, however it crushes admin-bar completely, and plugins like Chrome Ruler. This indicates that this method is plain wrong, however on user-end everything looks nice.

Any other way to do it?

Edit:

Ok, I found the solution.

Adding min-width to body itself does not help, but works when added to:

```
body.layout-full {

    min-width: 1080px;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you add `min-width:1080px` to `body`

Comment: @James it crushes admin-bar completely, and plugins like Chrome Ruler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

Adding min-width to body itself does not help, but works when added to:

```
body.layout-full {

    min-width: 1080px;
}
```